# Topological Insulator - why does a band have to be isolated to have a Chern number of 1?

Tags: topological-insulators

I'm trying to understand the principle of topological insulator.

Why a band has to be isolated to have a Chern number of 1? More precisely, why, in the case of Haldane Model, all the bands in the valence band don't participate with a Chern number of 1 as in the case of IntQHE?

Comment: "all the band in the valence band does not participate with a Chern number of 1" I'm not sure what this means, can  you be a little more clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an intuitive answer and a mathematical answer. Mathematically, the Chern number is defined as $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\epsilon^{ij} \langle\partial_i u|\partial_j u\rangle$. Thus, it requires you to have $|u\rangle$ be a locally differentiable function of $k$. But if a band touches another band, $|u\rangle$ can change abruptly across the band touching point. Intuitively, you know that the quantum Hall effect occurs exactly when you have zero longitudinal conductivity, so it only happens to insulators. Thus the bands can't touch.

Comment: Ok nice, thank you very much!